# Is it possible to determine the @Facebook.com email address of a user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to figure out reliably what the Facebook email of any Facebook user would be?  I know earlier this was not possible because not all users had a username.  But I believe that has changed since...

I'm trying to figure out a way to let a user send a direct message to their friend through my app.  The Request feature is pretty messed up now as you cannot send a custom message, which means most friends are probably going to ignore the request.

The type of messages that I am trying to let my users send to their friends would not be considered spam by Facebook, as these are messages sent directly from the user to their friend, except it is done through the app.  But it's pointless if the message just says "Joe wants you to try this app..."  The usefulness of an app on the Facebook platform is becoming questionable now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [facebook terms and conditions](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) disallow this...

> Facebook messaging (i.e., email sent to an @facebook.com address) is designed for communication between users, and not a channel for applications to communicate directly with users."

Despite your caveat at the end of your post I believe that facebook would consider this a message from your app to the user.

In terms of your question, then the user data returned includes 'username' which is the information you need to create the email address.

Comment: If it is okay for users to send email to a friend's facebook.com email address through Gmail or Yahoo, then why would it be inappropriate for them to send email through any other app?

Comment: Well facebook control the usage of their platform so they set the rules. It is also worth noting that you must get explicit consent from a user before posting to their email address "For all other data obtained through use of the Facebook API, you must obtain explicit consent from the user who provided the data to us before using it for any purpose other than displaying it back to the user on your application."

Comment: +1 other than the fact that @facebook email can differ from the username. (seen myself.) But not sure if username@facebook.com still works together with the one which is different from the username.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to figure out reliably what the Facebook email of any Facebook user would be? I know earlier this was not possible because not all users had a username. But I believe that has changed since...

Yes, now every user should have a username set – if not by themselves, than FB will have chosen one for them.

Besides that, I think writing to userid@facebook also works.

But I agree with combinatorial’s answer – Facebook explicitly says that this should not be used for app-to-user communication. To judge if your case is OK is up to you – otherwise you might consider using the send dialog instead, that’s more of the “designated” way to have users communicate “through” your app.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I realize it's a gray area and it's finally up to our business to decide if that would work for us. Just needed to know all my options.  So username@facebook.com would always work, and every user has a username?

Comment: I thought that the Send dialog was not available for mobile devices? I would love to find a way to use the Send Dialog if it were available.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is to give them a new message notification, it is not going to work. Because, if you send an email to the facebook email, it will land in the `Others` folder in the message box, which is like a spam box.Try mailing your own @facebook id and see what happens.

And Facebook doesnt give any documentation of how to get users @facebook email, most probably because they dont want developers to use it.

Why dont you mail them directly? You can easily get their email by adding `email` to the scope, and you can catch the email easily too.

> ```
> $data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxxxxx");
>
> $data = json_decode($data,true);
>
> $email = $data['email'];
> ```

Is that a viable option in your case?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Actually, what I'm trying to do is to allow a user to mail their friend directly form their own email address.  In this case, the message will not land up in the Other mailbox.  Also your suggestion of emailing them directly is not possible because when a user signs into my app using Facebook, I can request the user's email address, but not the user's friends' email addresses.

Comment: Ah, Yes, you `cant` grab your user's friends email addresses. I misread what you wanted to do. But well, as I checked some of my friend's @facebook email, they doesnt correspond to their username.